# Avoid Windows Form to crop image when resized

Tags: c#, wpf, image, crop, rendertransform

I'm currently working on a tool that allows to open multiple images in different windows. The main objective is to be able to move/resize the form and the image separately.
This is a very simple form containing a border, containing an image. 
I can pan & zoom the image using a transform group and everything works fine.

My problem is that if I resize the window to a smaller size than the image, and then move the image inside the window, the part of the image that was not visible after the resizing is cropped, and can only be retrieved when resizing the window itself.
It the same manner, if I reduce my image size then reduce the window size, the image will be cropped.

So I'm wondering what element cause that behavior, and is there a way to get rid of it ? Either by asking the form not to crop the image in the first place, or to redraw it when it is translated ?

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Toolboxproto.imgWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="imgWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStyle="None" 
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
    Activated="Window_Activated" 
    SizeChanged="Window_SizeChanged" 
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" MouseWheel="Window_MouseWheel"
    >

<Border x:Name="border" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gray" >
 <Image x:Name="image" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
  Height="290" 
  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
  Width="290" 
  MouseLeftButtonDown="image_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
  MouseWheel="image_MouseWheel" 
  MouseMove="image_MouseMove" 
  MouseLeftButtonUp="image_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
/>
```

[image: Screenshots]

Edit :
Here is the code for the translation and scale of the image, if relevant :

```
private void image_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
        {

            double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? 0.1 : -0.1;
            if ((e.Delta < 0) && (scaleT.ScaleX < 0.2 || scaleT.ScaleY < 0.2))
            { return; }


            Point relative = e.GetPosition(image);
            //Point absolute = new Point(0,0);

            double absoluteX = relative.X * scaleT.ScaleX + translateT.X;
            double absoluteY = relative.Y * scaleT.ScaleY + translateT.Y;

            scaleT.ScaleX += zoom;
            scaleT.ScaleY += zoom;

            translateT.X = absoluteX - relative.X * scaleT.ScaleX;
            translateT.Y = absoluteY - relative.Y * scaleT.ScaleY;
        }
}

 private void image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        if (image.IsMouseCaptured)
        {


            translateT.X = origin.X - (start.X - e.GetPosition(border).X);
            translateT.Y = origin.Y - (start.Y - e.GetPosition(border).Y);


        }

    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell when you don't show us the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I didn't put the code because I think it is probably more a problem about the behavior of the form or how wpf handle the image object. 
I added it in the original question.